# Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Tags: r, date, shiny

I am trying to plot my "PageLoads" column against my "Date column" from .csv as follows:

```
date<-as.character(df$Date)   # changing my Date column from factor to character class
df$Date <- as.Date( date, format="%m/%d/%Y") # changing it from character to Date class
print(ggplot( data = df, aes( Date, PageLoads )) + geom_line())  # lastly plotting it
```

but it gives the error: 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Please someone help me out of this...i will be highly thankful to you.

Comment: Could you provide some data. do a `dput(head(df, 10))`

Comment: print this as well df$Date

Comment: I tried doing dput(head(df,10)) and here are the results:structure(list(Day = structure(c(2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
12L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 2L), .Label = c("1-Dec-14", 
"10-Dec-14", "11-Dec-14", "12-Dec-14", "13-Dec-14"),class = "factor"), 
    PageLoads = c(7L, 20L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 17L
    )),Names = c("Day", "Date", "PageLoads"),row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I am not able to understand the above results..:P  and the results of View(df$Date) are as follows                                                                    1      1-Dec-14
2 2-Dec-14
3 3-Dec-14
4 4-Dec-14
5 5-Dec-14